# CSS3 NOT more FIRST-CHILD

Tags: css

Can I use `:not more :first-child`, its possible? 
I'm using the next code but does not work for me:

```
.navigation ul li:first-child:not([class]) a:before {
    content: ' [ '; }

.navigation ul li:not([class]):first-child a:before {
    content: ' [ '; }
```

[image]

I have this, 
but when I go to the first page breaks

all elements in the image are provided in the ul element

css for this pager is

```
.navigation{border-top: 1px solid #ccc;float: left; width: 100%;position: relative; text-align: center;padding-top: 5px;}
.navigation ul{text-decoration: none; list-style: none;}
.navigation ul li{display:inline !important;background: none !important;padding: 0px 1px !important;}
.navigation ul li a{display:inline !important;background: none !important;padding: 0px !important;color: inherit !important;text-decoration: none !important}
.navigation .next , .navigation .previous , .navigation .last , .navigation .first{position: absolute;}
.navigation ul li:nth-child(3) a:before{content: ' [ ';}
.navigation ul li:not([class]) a:after{content: ' |';}
.navigation ul li:nth-last-child(3) a:after{content: ' ]';}
.navigation .next {right: 30px;}
.navigation .previous {left: 30px;}
.navigation .last {right: 0;}
.navigation .first {left: 0;}
```

Comment: What is "more" supposed to mean here?

Comment: I think he means "chained with". Please could you also post your actual markup and explain what is the expected result?

Comment: yes "chained with", sorry i not speak english :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused by what first-child is doing here...

Assume a HTML format of this...

```
<ul>
    <li class="something">Something</li>
    <li>Somethign else</li>
    <li>Somethign else</li>
    <li>Somethign else</li>
    <li>Somethign else</li>
</ul>
```

With just this for CSS:

```
ul li:first-child { background: red; }
```

I get a result where the first LI has a red background: http://jsfiddle.net/L7wRD/

---

If I change the CSS to:

```
ul li:first-child:not(.something) { background: red; }
```

Then nothing happens unless there is another list where the first-child doesn't have the .something class.  Like this example:  http://jsfiddle.net/L7wRD/1/

---

I think what you are expecting is that the :not paired with the :first-child will ultimately select the second LI with the above given HTML.

Unfortunately, first-child is first-child.  It is ALWAYS the first element, and :not will not modify that.

Comment: thank you very much, you made me understand this better I fixed the first part. 

questions the same example you did not work in jsFiddle with no last-child?

Comment: works with last-child, but I was expecting something that is not. greetings and thanks